# Laptop screen goes black but still works

Tags: windows-8

I'm having a problem with my laptop, currently running Windows 8. My laptop screen goes black randomly but it is still running. What should I do? Hope you can help me and thank you.

Comment: Try connecting to an external monitor at this point. Try accessing the laptop over a network. What makes you say the computer is still working?

Comment: I can't see my GUI right now so I think I can't do anything right now.I accidentally switched my flash light on in front of the laptop's screen yesterday and I saw that it is still working(I mean I could see the screen because of the flashlight). :D

Comment: Are you suggesting that when you say it goes back, it actually is just very dark? It sounds like you have a power setting to make it dim... Does this only occur when low battery?

Comment: It sounds like the screen's backlight is failing.  If it's intermittent, it may just be a loose connection.

Comment: If its the backlight, shining a light at the screen would let you see what's on the display

Answer (score 0):

I work in hardware repair so I hope my experience can help you solve your problem. Typically when I see this exact type of issue, I look for these things in this order:

1. Connect the laptop to an external monitor or TV to confirm that it is in fact running.
2. Make sure the ribbon that connects the LCD to the motherboard is not loose. (common)
3. Check to see if the ribbon that connects the LCD to the motherboard is bad. (rare)
4. Check to see if the LCD itself is the culprit by replacing it. (common)

What you describe seems like it's an issue with the connection, especially if it "goes out randomly." I would guess that it goes out whenever you move your laptop's screen?